# LWC lightning-tree-grid Remove Wrap Text/Clip Text Options from

Tags: lightning-web-components, remove, tree-component

I need some help in removing Wrap Text/Clip Text options for tree grid.
[image]

I need to do it at least for Name column. The reason of that is that for some long names wrap option isn't working as expected - it's exceeded cell like below:

[image]

I didn't found the reason why is that happening, so I decided to remove these options as they're not required in my project.

Initially when I was working on that in datatable I used hideDefaultActions: "true" for the column and it was working, but for tree-grid it not.

I tried add hideDefaultActions: "true" in the table declaration, tried CSS described here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005emkQAA
but they're seem to be working only for datatable.

Does anyone know how we can hide/remove these options?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm also having this problem. Please let me know if you've find a solution.

Comment: Hi @Andegosu Yes, I found the solution! The lightning-tree-grid I wrapped in additional div and next in CSS file I applied styles to this div. See my updated post.

Comment: @Tom2341 Please, add your solution as an answer here (not as an update to the question), you can accept your own answer as well. It will help people searching for solution to find it the easiest way possible.

Comment: For anyone struggling with this issue, I solved it by below:  

lightning-tree-grid wrap by additional div and apply below CSS formatting.  

Table from HTML:

<div class ="wrapword">
            <lightning-tree-grid
            columns={columns}
            data={myData}
            key-field="Id"
            hide-checkbox-column="true"
        ></lightning-tree-grid>
</div>

Comment: Applied CSS formatting:  

.wrapword{  
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important; /*Mozilla, since 1999*/  
    white-space: -webkit-pre-wrap; /*Chrome and Safari */  white-space: -pre-wrap; /*Opera 4-6*/  white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /*Opera 7*/  white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */  word-wrap: break-word; /*Internet Explorer 5.5+ */  word-break: break-all; 
 white-space: normal;  }  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

we need to do this using custom CSS and follow the below approach using static resource

step 1 -> Create a custom CSS file
[image]

step 2 -> Upload this file in static resource
[image]

step 3 -> Now in js make a render call like below
[image]

HTML code
[image]

**For any further Query**

Linkedin Id -> [www.linkedin.com/in/manishmanghnani/](http://www.linkedin.com/in/manishmanghnani/)

Comment: Pasting screenshots of code is generally discouraged, because the code can't be copy/pasted and search engines face difficulties with images. The LinkedIn link points to your person and appears therefore like self promotion. For any further query I'd recommend the comments. Finally, I'm missing some cautionary remarks regarding the proposed solution, because couldn't this stop working anytime, if Salesforce chooses to use another class?!